# An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Can someone advice me how to prevent this error. An item with the same key has already been added.?

```
//  Failed to find a matching SessionFactory so make a new one.
        if (sessionFactory == null)
        {
            Check.Require(File.Exists(sessionFactoryConfigPath),
                          "The config file at '" + sessionFactoryConfigPath + "' could not be found");

            Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
            cfg.Configure(sessionFactoryConfigPath);

            /*MINE*/
            var persistenceModel = new PersistenceModel();
            persistenceModel.AddMappingsFromAssembly(Assembly.Load("EMedicine.Core"));
            persistenceModel.Configure(cfg);
            /*END_OF_MINE*/

            //  Now that we have our Configuration object, create a new SessionFactory
            sessionFactory = cfg.BuildSessionFactory();

            if (sessionFactory == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("cfg.BuildSessionFactory() returned null.");
            }

            if (sessionFactoryConfigPath != null) sessionFactories.Add(sessionFactoryConfigPath, sessionFactory);
        }
```

Error is here:
sessionFactory = cfg.BuildSessionFactory();

Comment: Do you have sources of the cfg.BuildSessionFactory() method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
if (
    sessionFactoryConfigPath != null && 
    sessionFactories.ContainsKey(sessionFactoryConfigPath)
) {
    sessionFactory = cfg.BuildSessionFactory();

    if (sessionFactory == null)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("cfg.BuildSessionFactory() returned null.");
    }

    sessionFactories.Add(sessionFactoryConfigPath, sessionFactory);
} else (sessionFactoryConfigPath != null) {
    sessionFactory = sessionFactories[sessionFactoryConfigPath];
}
```

Comment: Thx for your answer but now i get Object reference not set to an instance of an object in second else statement

if (interceptor != null)
                {
                    session = GetSessionFactoryFor(sessionFactoryConfigPath).OpenSession(interceptor);
                }
                else
                {
                    session = GetSessionFactoryFor(sessionFactoryConfigPath).OpenSession();
                }

Comment: Just retrieve the existing sessionFactory ... see Edit.

Comment: i modified else statement to else if (sessionFactoryConfigPath != null) 
                {
                    sessionFactory = (ISessionFactory) sessionFactories[sessionFactoryConfigPath];
                } but it is the same. What if if statement will be like if (sessionFactoryConfigPath != null && !sessionFactories.ContainsValue(sessionFactory)) 
                {

Comment: If you are using VS see what variable is null. And then try to find out why it is null. From what I have seen from your code I would look at the session creation above and try to find out why the session is not created.

Comment: All the time is problem this line:  sessionFactory = cfg.BuildSessionFactory(); Problem is that if connect to app 4 times at the same time crashes.

Comment: Obalix what if i use try catch block? Is it smart?

Comment: Not really, IMHO it is smarter to find another way to limit the executions of this section of code. One way could be the use of a singleton, but I do not know whether this fits your application design. Another way could be to use a flag that indicates whether the section of code has executed. And yet another, if you have multiple threads, could be the use of a `lock (lockobject) { }` block. But as I said it depends upon the requriements and the design of you application.

Comment: Hi, thx for your answer.

Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
cfg.Configure(sessionFactoryConfigPath);

Found the problem. I need to check if key (cfg.BuildSessionFactory()) already exist. Maybe do you know any methods for this?

Answer (score 0):

Is this solution OK?

```
try
                    {
                        //  Now that we have our Configuration object, create a new SessionFactory
                        sessionFactory = cfg.BuildSessionFactory();

                        if (sessionFactory == null)
                        {
                            throw new InvalidOperationException("cfg.BuildSessionFactory() returned null.");
                        }

                        if (sessionFactoryConfigPath != null)
                            sessionFactories.Add(sessionFactoryConfigPath, sessionFactory);
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    { 
                        if (sessionFactoryConfigPath != null)
                            sessionFactory = (ISessionFactory) sessionFactories[sessionFactoryConfigPath];
                    }
```